# How to get error code 500 in symfony 6 custom error controller

Tags: php, symfony, exception, error-handling, symfony6

I have this code:

```
#[AsController]
class Error {

    public function show($exception) {
        var_dump(
            $exception->getCode(),
            $exception->getMessage()
        );
        die;
    }

}
```

And in config:

```
framework:
    secret: '%env(APP_SECRET)%'
    #csrf_protection: true
    http_method_override: false
    error_controller: App\Controller\Error::show
```

If I getting 404 error, then in `exception->getCode()` I got answer 404.
If I getting 500 error, then in `exception->getCode()` I got answer 0, but in `exception->getMessage()` method I got needed message: `Idle timeout reached for "http://badsite.com:7080/api/v1/base/pages/werwerwer`.
If I turn of `error_controller` config - then I got 500 exception.

I need to get error code 500 too in my custom Error controller with `exception->getCode()` method.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this code will help to get the desired value:

```php
$errorCode = method_exists($exception, 'getStatusCode')
    ? $exception->getStatusCode()
    : $exception->getCode()
;
```